# Notepad++ regular expression remove parts of string

Tags: notepad++

I want to remove some strings with notepad++ but can't find the correct regular expression:

```
"This text is ok. This part should be removed","More Text that should stay"
```

i am looking for something like: Find "This part" and remove everything until the first ",

Comment: What are the rules? Please give sample text and expected result.

Comment: This is what it should look after the find and replace: "This text is ok.","More Text that should stay"

Comment: Without real example **and** the rules to select, it's impossible to answer. As is, I can suggest: Replace `This part should be removed` with nothing, it works with your test case but I'm sure that is not what you want! You must give more details.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:
Replace: This text is ok. (.|\r\n)*?(",)